# Can I use freetts to detect a specific sound from audio input?

Tags: java, speech-to-text, freetts

Can I use [freetts](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php) to do something like speech to text convert?

I need to detect a specific sound from audio input from my laptop, can I do this by [freetts](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php) in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, see "[Where is the speech recognizer?](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php#where_is_recognizer)" in the freetts FAQ.